# how to log http request body and headers while handle error in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IErrorHandler

Tags: wcf, http

WCF gurus,

you probably already know the answer I cannot find ...

let's say I have some web service (WCF) and a client application (based on curl library). **Sometimes** on the server site I got the strange error:

> The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true).
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true).
>   Source: System.ServiceModel
>   Stack trace:
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
>   Rethrown as: 
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation '...'. The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true).
>   Source: System.ServiceModel
>   Stack trace:
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>   ...

On the client site I see (in the log) that a client sends a request and the request is not empty (has some body) but I would like to verify that WCF receives this request from the wire.
How can I do that? 
Ideally I would log an incoming request (raw bytes) in the error handler like System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IErrorHandler, otherwise collect the data somewhere and then log them while the error happens (some kind of low-level http traffic proxy on the server side?).

Another solution could be install Wireshark on the server site but I prefer avoid it because it happens on customer site and I do not have any access to her machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried WCF Message logging?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

Comment: Not yet. As far as I understand it would log messages instead of raw requests. I will try it definetely if I do not find another way how to log the incoming data in my log file.

Comment: True, it will not give you the kind of raw TCP view you would get with wireshark but it should show you what message WCF was trying to deserilize when it threw the exception and you should be able to work back from there to find what happened if you have a client and a service side log to compare.

Comment: Once I tried to use WCF Message logging for another issues but I gave up after some attempts. I found that it would be good tool if I can switch it on/off on the server site **without restart the server** and can log the messages in my log file in the format proper for log file otherwise I would have to modify feedback application which automatically collect all logs to send me. Maybe something changed since then and I need to try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I found good a little bit complicated solution. If you need to do something like what I have asked in the question, you need to implement `MessageEncoder` and install it via `MessageEncodingBindingElement`. Override `ReadMessage(...)` methods in `MessageEncoder`, there you will have access to the buffer that contains raw incoming body.